# Installshield: file duplicate because of merge module

Tags: installshield, merge-module

I have an InstallShield (2018, also happens in IS 11) setup with a lot of 3th party libraries. Among other things a merge module. This merge module have a file (call F).

Now, there is an other library as a directory with a bunch of different files, sadly also a file with the name "F".

I can't add this file:

[image: Error 1: F Reason: The file belongs to a merge module]

A work around is creating a new merge module just containing this file and adding it to the feature. But the drawback is: When updating the libary directory, the merge module has also to be updated. But do I remember at this moment to this? What if other persons are doing this? So I want to avoid this work around. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is i removed merge module from the project and re-added them after adding files to the project.

Comment: This is working? Even I deselect the msm, the check is done. I have to remove the files first. But I'm doing this on an other way now: extract the files and definition, and add it to the setup. Was necessary, because we want to sign the files - for logo validation.